# ksqlDB - How to explode rows for each day between 2 timestamp columns?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I have a topic that contains a `startDate` and an `endDate` attribute. When building the stream I would like to [explode](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/table-functions/#explode) the single row into multiple rows, one for each day between start and end dates. For didactic reasons, I'm converting timestamps into string dates in the examples below.

Input data:

```json
{ "id": 1, "startDate": "2023-03-01", "endDate": "2023-03-05" }
{ "id": 2, "startDate": "2023-03-02", "endDate": "2023-03-06" }
```

Some initial stream loading from the topic:

```sql
CREATE STREAM mystream (
   id INT
  ,startDate TIMESTAMP
  ,endDate TIMESTAMP
>) WITH (
  kafka_topic='mytopic',
  value_format='json',
  partitions=1
);
```

The desired streaming result after transformations and explosions:

```json
{ "id": 1, "date": "2023-03-01" }
{ "id": 1, "date": "2023-03-02" }
{ "id": 1, "date": "2023-03-03" }
{ "id": 1, "date": "2023-03-04" }
{ "id": 1, "date": "2023-03-05" }
{ "id": 2, "date": "2023-03-02" }
{ "id": 2, "date": "2023-03-03" }
{ "id": 2, "date": "2023-03-04" }
{ "id": 2, "date": "2023-03-05" }
{ "id": 2, "date": "2023-03-06" }
```

Is it possible to do something like this with ksqlDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked the question in the ksqlDB forum and got an answer there:
https://forum.confluent.io/t/how-to-explode-rows-for-each-day-between-2-timestamp-columns/7323

So I basically need to create a user-defined table function following the steps [here](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/create-a-user-defined-function/#tabular-functions).

The Java program to do the magic is here:

```java
package com.example;

import io.confluent.ksql.function.udtf.Udtf;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udtf.UdtfDescription;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udf.UdfParameter;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

functions
@UdtfDescription(name = "date_explode",
         author = "Rafael",
         version = "1.0.0",
         description = "Given a start and end date, explode the period into a list of dates.")
public class DateExplodeUdtf {

  @Udtf(description = "start and end date are days from epoch")
  public List<Timestamp> dateExplode(
    @UdfParameter(value = "startDate", description = "start date (days from epoch)") final Integer startDate,
    @UdfParameter(value = "endDate", description = "end date (days from epoch)") final Integer endDate
  ) {
    List<Timestamp> result = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate startDateComputed = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(startDate);
    LocalDate endDateComputed = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(endDate);
    for (LocalDate date = startDateComputed; !date.isAfter(endDateComputed); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
      result.add(Timestamp.valueOf(date.atStartOfDay()));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

And when running:

```sql
SELECT
   id
  ,DATE_EXPLODE(startDate, endDate) AS date
FROM mystream;
```